# Why do I get errors when I call IShellFolder._Release?

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-shell

I use windows shell to enumerate items in the control panel and add item name in memo , in the end release `IShellFolder` and `PITEMIDLIST` but get error.

Code :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  psfDeskTop : IShellFolder;
  psfControl : IShellFolder;
  pidControl : PITEMIDLIST;
  pidChild : PITEMIDLIST;
  pidAbsolute : PItemIdList;
  pEnumList : IEnumIDList;
  celtFetched : ULONG;
  FileInfo : SHFILEINFOW;

begin

  OleCheck(SHGetDesktopFolder(psfDeskTop));
  OleCheck(SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(0, CSIDL_CONTROLS, pidControl));
  OleCheck(psfDeskTop.BindToObject(pidControl, nil, IID_IShellFolder,
    psfControl));
  OleCheck(psfControl.EnumObjects(0, SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS or SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN
    or SHCONTF_FOLDERS, pEnumList));
  while pEnumList.Next(1, pidChild, celtFetched) = 0 do
  begin

    pidAbsolute := ILCombine(pidControl, pidChild);
    SHGetFileInfo(LPCTSTR(pidAbsolute), 0, FileInfo, SizeOf(FileInfo),
      SHGFI_PIDL or SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(FileInfo.szDisplayName);

  end;
  //OK
  psfDeskTop._Release;
  //Error
  psfControl._Release;
  //Error
  //pEnumList._Release;
  CoTaskMemFree(pidControl);
  CoTaskMemFree(pidChild);
  CoTaskMemFree(pidAbsolute);
end;
```

Why it's Ok to release `psfDeskTop` but get error when release `psfControl and pEnumList` ?  is there any other way to release them ? or do I need some judgement before i release them?

Comment: not sure, try to release in reverse as you acquired them...

Comment: Don't call `_Release`. If you ever need to let go of your hold on an interface write `intf := nil`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan like this : `psfDeskTop := nil;pEnumList := nil;` ?

Comment: Yes, like that. Why do you want to do so though? It will happen automatically when the variables go out of scope.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I thought somethings not used must free or release,just like classs. now it seems I was wrong . thank you.

Comment: FYI, your loop has a memory leak.  You need to free `pidChild` with `CoTaskMemFree()` when you are done using it, before you call `pEnumList.Next()` again. Don't free it outside of the loop, that is too late. You need to free it inside of the loop instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interfaced Objects are released by internal referencecounter, there is not need to release them (You shall not release them).